# Can I write this jQuery to be less selector specific?

Tags: jquery

When creating a one page site I often choose to have a fixed header, which highlights page links as you scroll down, in order to do this I usually end up writing quite a few lines of jQuery and I was just wondering, is there a way of writing this that would require no specific selectors?

If for example I was to have 10 links this code could get quite heavy, can I change it so that no mater how many links/sections I have it still functions properly (and so it still work with a CMS that creates links and sections automatically)?

**[LINK TO DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3y8vP/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {

// Sets a variable for the distance scrolled from the top of the page

        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

// Sets variables for the distance of each section from the top of the whole
// page (40 is the height of the fixed header, so that it applies the class when
// the bottom of the header reaches the 'page' instead of the top of the window)

        var sectionOne = ( $('#section_one').offset().top - 40);
        var sectionTwo = ( $('#section_two').offset().top - 40);
        var sectionThree = ( $('#section_three').offset().top - 40);

// If distance from top of page is greater than or equal to than the variables 
// set earlier then apply class to relevant link and remove from ANY others ... 
// ELSE remove class from relevant link

        if (y >= sectionOne) {
            $('.link_1').addClass('active');
            $('.link_2').removeClass('active');
            $('.link_3').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.link_1').removeClass('active');
        }

// Repeat for other section and link

        if (y >= sectionTwo) {
            $('.link_2').addClass('active');
            $('.link_1').removeClass('active');
            $('.link_3').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.link_2').removeClass('active');
        }

// Repeat for other section and link

        if (y >= sectionThree) {
            $('.link_3').addClass('active');
            $('.link_1').removeClass('active');
            $('.link_2').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.link_3').removeClass('active');
        }

// and so on

    }); 
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a `.link` class to all your links, to simplify the code. Then you'll be able to loop over your links and generalize your treatment :

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="link link_1 active" href="#section_one">Section One</a></li>
            <li><a class="link link_2" href="#section_two">Section Two</a></li>
            <li><a class="link link_3" href="#section_three">Section Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>    
</header>

<section id="section_one"></section>
<section id="section_two"></section>
<section id="section_three"></section>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

        $('.link').each(function(event) {
            if(y >= $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 40) {
                $('.link').not(this).removeClass('active'); 
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });

    });
});
```

[**Update JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3y8vP/2/)

If you reach `section_one`, `link_1` will be active.
If you reach `section_two`, `link_2` will be active, and `link_1` inactive (thanks to the `$('.link').not(this)` selector).